# Why does django need a database for custom authentication backends?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I implemented a django custom authentication backend. My *authenticate()* returns a user object like this `return User(username=username, password=password)`, but I never store the User object to a database.

1. Why do do the django docs recommend creating a database with user objects? (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend - "...the best way to deal with this is to create a Django User object for each user that exists for your backend...")
2. If I try calling *login()*, there's a call made to the database. If logins are stored in sessions, why is a database necessary? (Using cached sessions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you specifically need to *save* the `User` object is that it's common for apps to create database level relationships between objects and users (in order to persist the relationship across multiple requests).

A simple example would be the activity log in `django.contrib.admin`. It displays recent behaviour that users have performed. This only works when the user object is saved to the database.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. It just seems weird to me to have users stored in two different databases 1) the custom backend 2) django database. For example, if a user changes their password, there is some extra bookkeeping that needs to get done, to make sure the changes are done in both places.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly awkward for your use-case. The whole `auth.User` situation is an area of ongoing discussion regarding how to make it more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

Quite a few apps have a foreign key to `auth.User`; if you don't have that table populated then you don't get to use those apps.